# adding second filter condition produces error

Tags: powershell

As soon as put in the -and command, I get an error.  I know it has to do with the syntax but google is not providing me with anything that worked.

```
gwmi -namespace Root\cimv2 -class win32_product -impersonation 3 -Filter { Name like "%Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86%" -and Version -eq "9.0.30729.6161"}
```

Comment: `Get-WmiObject`'s `-Filter` parameter is a string that uses [WQL syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606.aspx). (Always helpful to look at the help, which states this explicitly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Get-WmiObject`, the `-Filter` parameter expects you to use [WQL (WMI Query Language) syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx) - `-eq` and `-and` or not valid WQL operators:

```
Get-WmiObject -Filter 'Name LIKE "%Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86%" AND Version = "9.0.30729.6161"' -namespace Root\cimv2 -class win32_product -impersonation 3
```

Comment: Here is a WQL syntax link to help NobleMan sort out queries in the future: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx